# how do I get to the aether

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I watched YouTube and looked up how to make ateher portal and they showed every step how to and I did everything it never worked  I am starting to think that you can only get there with the mod and that they had the mod I play Minecraft pe so I thought they may not have it in the game yet is this all true?

Answer (score 2):

The portal you are trying to make is from a mod [The Aether PE](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-texture-packs/1973170-the-aether-pe).